# Access application with only domain name

Tags: apache-2.4, redirection

I've an application deployed in Tomcat with Apache as a webserver. So, when user hit the URL : `https://foobar.com/foo` , the application page is rendered. I've a redirect configuration done in httpd.conf as follows

```
ProxyPass        /foo  https://dreams.pok.com:2820/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo  https://dreams.pok.com:2820/foo
```

Now the problem is, I want my users to just hit https://foobar.com and automatically get redirected to `https://foobar.com/foo`.

How can this be achieved please ...?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have *mod_rewrite* enabled you can use

```
Redirect / /foo
Redirect /index.html /foo
```

Another option would be to edit you index file or redirect using headers.

Comment: /foo is actually getting redirected to my tomcat application server. There is no index.html.